# How to search for a term with any combination of letters, numbers and _ symbol with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have several terms containing both capital and lower case letters, numbers and the _ symbol i.e. "3133_1026_b_b13" and I would like to use the findall function to search for it. I have tried:

```
findal("([A-Za-z1-9_)*", file.html)
```

but this only returns numbers up to a certain point i.e. "3133_1"

What regex operators and order do I need to achieve this?

Comment: `findall` **not** `findal`, your regex also contains syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

You need to include 0 as well. It's findall not findal as Pedro Lobito points out. You didn't have a closing ]. You don't need the (). A + works better than * as * matches an empty string because a + matches one or more of the preceding characters where a * matches zero or more of the preceding characters.

```
import re
data="3133_1026_b_b13 3133_1026_b_b14"
print (re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9_]+", data))
```

outputs:

```
['3133_1026_b_b13', '3133_1026_b_b14']
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question